# Платформонезависимый Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Как можно определить в Makefile, под какую ОС компилируется программа?
Желательно знать, хотя бы, в пределах IOS/Android/Windows/Linux. Хотелось бы иметь общий файл, в котором будут подключаться библиотеки в зависимости от OS.

Comment: Стоит создавать отдельную тему для каждого вопроса. Зачем может понадобиться определять наличие дефайнов? Вот в мире gnu/linux реализовали идею определять наличие в окружении определенных фич путем автоматизированных тестов перед сборкой (в autotools), но ничего кроме замедления сборки и жонглирования костылями она не принесла.

Comment: если кратко, то можно, но не практично... обычно для конфигурации пользуются другими системами сборки, большинство из которых по факту являются надстройками над `make`, как то `autotools`/`cmake`/`qmake` и др.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос поставлен с ног на голову. это **вы** указываете, под какую платформу надо компилировать программу. и указываете это в первую очередь **компилятору**, а не интерпретатору *make*.

конечно, если делаете это через переменные окружения, то можно добавить какую-то обработку в программу, предназначенную для интерпретатора *make*.

интерпретатор *make* понимает разные виды условных конструкций:

- [условные операторы](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html)
- [условные функции](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html)

например, запишите в `makefile` такую программу:

```
цель:
ifeq ($(собираемся-под),супер-ось)
  @echo 'ура! собираемся под нашу супер-ось'
else
  @echo 'собираемся под фигню какую-то'
endif
```

примеры вывода (только для *gnu/make*):

```
$ make
собираемся под фигню какую-то
$ make собираемся-под=супер-ось
ура! собираемся под нашу супер-ось
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит упомянуть, что `ifeq` является расширением GNU Make. Нативный Make какого-нибудь \*BSD вас не поймёт. Там надо условия прятать в sh.